# ExactTarget JAVA-SDK - Turn off logging of each SOAP Call

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, java, logging, fuel-sdk

Please advise on how to turn off the SDK logging of each SOAP Call.  I must be missing something obvious...Thank you!

Comment: If this answered your question - be sure to check the mark so we all know it is!

Answer (score 1):

As of version [0.9999](https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Java/releases/tag/v0.9999) the Java SDK supports controlling the log level of Apache CXF via log4j.resources. To turn off logging altogether you can do this:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=OFF
```